# I have a with getCmp in extjs 3

Tags: extjs3

I wanted to ask about the definition of

```
Ext.getCmp('').root.reload();
Ext.getCmp('').getForm().reset();
Ext.getCmp('').focus(false, 500);
Ext.getCmp('').getSelectionModel().getSelectedNode();
Ext.getCmp('').getForm().setValues();
Ext.getCmp('').getSelectionModel().getSelectedNode();
```

and function of Ext.getCmp

Answer (score 0):

you can check:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp

Also, getCmp is not recommended for the coding. But do helpful for the learning, debug and hack. I like this screencast:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109307-Screencast-quot-The-dangers